# Drupal - Validate form before submit / Encrypt password before send it

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

I would like to modify (encrypt) the login password in Drupal, before it sends it decrypted to server. I didn't find any module to do that (validation before submission), and I couldn't find a way of validate the fields before they are sent to server.

Is there a way to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this module will help you [Encryption](http://drupal.org/project/encrypt)

Answer (score -1):

Create your custom module and use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a new custom validation and submission callbacks:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == "user_profile_form") {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'your_new_validation_callback';
        $form['#submit'][] = 'your_new_submission_callback';
    }
}

function your_new_validation_callback($form, &$form_state)
{
    // add your validation logic
}

function your_new_submission_callback($form, &$form_state)
{
    // add your submission logic
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! But I would need the validation "before" it sends from client-side to server-side. This way it won't work, will it?
Thanks!

Comment: That's the whole purpose of validation. It is called **before** submission. And if something goes wrong you can use [`form_set_error`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/6) to file an error against a form element. In which case your submission function is not reached.

Comment: As far as http traffic goes, the op is right: this way does not alter the data that gets sent from the browser to the server. The validation only kicks in when the data reaches the server un the form of an HTTP POST request.